# Get all users with userGroups

Tags: django

I am trying to write a method which can return all the users from django defaultDb. The following would result in giving me all the users:

```
User.objects.all()
```

Now, I want to add usergroups to each of the user as part of my response. I know I can parse every user and get usergroup like:

```
user.groups.values_list('name',flat=True)
```

But I feel this is very expensive operation as it involves n read from Db for n users. Is there any other better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to fetch all related groups in 1 additional query

```
User.objects.prefetch_related('groups')
```

Now you can loop over all users and then access each users groups without incurring additional DB accesses